# Is this a US military armored vehicle modified for railroad use?

Tags: united-states, military, transportation

Is the vehicle depicted below some form of US military armored vehicle modified for use on railroads? Is it an MRAP so modified? Is it self-powered or simply able to be towed by a locomotive?

[image: Image of armored vehicle captioned as modified MRAP]

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, use an answer.

Comment: Unanswerable question. A reverse google image linked back to the person who photopgrahed [this](https://www.flickr.com/photos/potjie/3405993963/), he captions it as a Padda, which is **a landmine-protected infantry mobility vehicle that has been in use in South Africa for over 30 years**.

Comment: @georgechalhoub When I use Google image search it returns many copies of the image. How do you use it to find the earliest or original copy of an image?

Comment: @ChrisW, it depends on each image search. For instance, this [image search](http://goo.gl/71Q4DW) had 2 pages only of results. I checked them all and none was dated older than the image on pixlr (the date is available either from google or from the post). Pixlr(reputable) had it mentioned also the camera which took the photo "Pentax K100D", and also the users profile has all original photos. One general rule:Google SERP algorithms are extremely smart, and can't be fooled so they will index the first occurrence in the first page. Usually, this is original search and won't be accepted here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost certainly not.

Google and Tineye reverse image searches both trace back to [this image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/potjie/3405993963/) on Flickr, which describes it as a "Padda" armored patrol vehicle used by the South African railways.  Google image searching on variations of "padda armored vehicle" bring up similar-looking images such as [this one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/77106958@N08/6908287975/).  Perhaps there's mass confusion between a jerry-rigged rail MRAP and the "Padda" (there's precedent: the depicted vehicle has also been misidentified as a rail-adapted version of the [Casspir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casspir) landmine-protected vehicle), but more likely, it's exactly what the Flickr caption says it is.

Comment: Indeed, an earlier commenter found concrete evidence that this specific vehicle is on display at a railway museum in Namibia.